# Options in select field only appearing after switching tab

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a problem with a `<select>` in my code. As you can see in the picture when I reach this point in the checkout the options are hidden in a strange way.

[image]

When I just switch the tab and go back everything is fine.

[image]

The code is:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'payone_iframe_min.js?' + window.location.search.substring(1);

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<select id="cardexpiremonth" style="width: 113px;">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

I just can't figure out why this happens or how I can resolve this. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: I don’t see how your example code that you have given right now - a mere select field, nothing else - could possibly help reproduce this. There is likely a lot more of the surrounding code necessary as well to reproduce this specific situation.

Comment: updated the rest of the code .. I believe it comes from the iframe

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything wrong with this. I tested in Chrome and Firefox. Maybe it is because of `<option value="0"></option>` because it is empty. but that should work.

```html
<select id="cardexpiremonth" style="width: 100px;">
 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I also could find out that this only happens in chrome oO